# How to use Update Panel with Gridview to restrict page load?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, updatepanel

I am using three linkbutton's inside a div tag and a gridview. On clicking link button it changes the gridview data. I want to use update panel for gridview to restrict page_load(). So that on clicking link button it only refresh the gridview part and not the whole page.

```
`<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkcot" runat="server" onclick="Link_Click">Cotton</asp:LinkButton><font color="#5D7B9D">||</font>
       <asp:LinkButton ID="lnktex" runat="server" onclick="Link_Click">Textile</asp:LinkButton><font color="#5D7B9D">||</font>
       <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkgar" runat="server" onclick="Link_Click">Garments</asp:LinkButton>`
`<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" ShowHeader="False" 
           ForeColor="Black" GridLines="None" EnableModelValidation="True" 
           onpageindexchanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" onrowcreated="GridView1_RowCreated">
           <Columns>
               <asp:TemplateField>
                   <ItemTemplate>
                       <ul style="margin:7px 0 0 17px; color:#06F;"><li>
                           <asp:HyperLink ID="HLNWS" runat="server" ForeColor="Black" 
                               NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("nid","news_details.aspx?id={0}") %>' 
                               Text='<%# Eval("headlines_n") %>'></asp:HyperLink>
                           &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="lblnws" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("nid") %>' 
                               Visible="False"></asp:Label>
                       </li></ul>
                   </ItemTemplate>
               </asp:TemplateField>
           </Columns>
       </asp:GridView>`
```

Please guide me how can I use update panel in this case.

Comment: Just place your gridview and linkbutton insode the update panel.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter But then I have a doubt that how I can use
`<Triggers>
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="" EventName="" />
</Triggers>`
Since I am using three link buttons, then what should be the Control ID?

Comment: What do the other 2 linkbuttons do? Do you want all 3 to cause refresh of the grid only or do u want the other 2 to cause full refresh?

Comment: Thanks a lot @YuriyGalanter I tried what you suggested. and it worked.